# Reload search results on new search in web application (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api

I have a simple web app that uses an API to return search results from a database and uses ajax to insert them into an empty ul element on the page. (Using JSONP with a cross domain request)

I cant figure out how to do it using javascript, everywhere I've found uses jQuery. I want to be able to have them enter another search term and have it clear the existing content from the page.

Currently if you conduct a second search it just appends the new results to the bottom of the existing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using a few simple lines of html when onsubmit occurs with the search field:

```
var div = document.getElementById('cart_item');

while(div.firstChild){
    div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the content (returned from your API call using AJAX) you just can assign it to your `ul` or `div` e.g. `document.getElementById('YourULID').innerHTML = "The content you got from your AJAX call"`

Comment: I've got that part working, but if they conduct a second or third etc search without reloading the page, it just adds more and more list items to my ul. I need a way to clear it out and reload each time a user conducts a search.

Comment: you should clear it out using `document.getElementById('YourULID').innerHTML = ''`

Comment: Check your API code which returns the result, as we are assigning innerHTML it should simply replace it.  Your API may be returning appended results i think.

Comment: I figured it out using a simple few lines of HTML when onsubmit occurs:

var clear = document.getElementById('list');
while(clear.firstChild){
    clear.removeChild(clear.firstChild);
}

Answer (score 0):

*From vanilla.js (so you can [compare with jQuery](http://vanilla-js.com)):*

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("POST", "path/to/api", true);
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
  alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
};
r.send("banana=yellow");
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you want. You want to get result from server and insert them into a ul form field of your webpage.
This is just an example and might help

```
function createRequest(){
    try{
       request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    }catch (tryMS){
        try{
            request = new ActivXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (otherMS){
            try{
                request = new ActivXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (failed){
                request = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return request;
}

function loggin(user_id,password){
    request = createRequest();
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('user_id',user_id.value);
    data.append('password',password.value);
    request.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(request == null){
            alert('Unable to connect');
        }else{
            if(request.readyState==4){
                if(request.status==200){
                    if(request.responseText){
                        document.location.href = request.responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will create and HTTP request. Post data to your server then fetch the result and throw it back to your javascript, then staight to your webpage. Use **request.responseText** to append/insert to the appropriate field

Comment: ive already build the app using JSONP. everything works fine. the problem however im experiencing is when a second or third or more search is conducted, it just adds them to my list. i want to be able to clear the ul each time a search is conducted.